# django-permission == 0.8.0, code in readthedocs not working?

Tags: python, django

I am following the code in the readthedocs (http://django-permission.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  Difficulty starts at *Apply permission logic* section of the docs. All works fine as I cut&paste

```
art1 = Article.objects.create(
title="Article 1",
body="foobar hogehoge",
author=user1
)
```

The following traceback is generated

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 4, in <module>
File "C:\Django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 157, in create
return self.get_queryset().create(**kwargs)
File "C:\Django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 320, in create
obj = self.model(**kwargs)
File "C:\Django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 417, in __init__
raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % list(kwargs)[0])
TypeError: 'author' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

If it is changed to

```
art1 = Project.objects.create(
    rest of code is okay
```

It works okay. So I guess an error. Maybe, I'm unsure.

Anyway, still cut&paste into shell until I get to

```
>>> assert user1.has_perm('permission.change_article') == False
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
```

So I try

```
>>> assert user1.has_perm('permission.change_article') == True
```

Works fine.  I have to say at this stage I have no idea as to what is going on.

So next line is

```
assert user1.has_perm('permission.change_article', art1) == True
```

And now the traceback

```
   >>> assert user1.has_perm('permission.change_article', art1) == True
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
   File "c:\django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 336, in has_perm return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj)
   File "c:\django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 273, in _user_has_perm if backend.has_perm(user, perm, obj):
   File "c:\django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\permission\backends.py", line 71, in has_perm if handler.has_perm(user_obj, perm, obj=obj):
   File "c:\django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\permission\handlers.py", line 237, in has_perm if permission_logic.has_perm(user_obj, perm, obj):
   File "c:\django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\permission\logics\author.py", line 122, in has_perm author = field_lookup(obj, self.field_name)
   File "c:\django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\permission\utils\field_lookup.py", line 42, in field_lookup return field_lookup(field_lookup(obj, field_path[0]), field_path[1])
   File "c:\django\test_permissions\lib\site-packages\permission\utils\field_lookup.py", line 41, in field_lookup return getattr(obj, field_path[0])
   AttributeError: 'Project' object has no attribute 'project'
```

Have I done something wrong?
I have no idea what to do.  I am as far out as Bishops Rock Lighthouse  ;-)

I need to get permissions working for my project.  Is this the app to go with?

BTW.

```
  (test_permissions) c:\django\test_permissions\test_permissions>pip freeze
    Django==1.6.5
    Pillow==2.2.2
    South==0.8.4
    app-version==0.1.2
    django-appconf==0.6
    django-crispy-forms==1.4.0
    django-permission==0.8.0
    six==1.7.0
    tolerance==0.1.1
```

Working in virtualenv on Win7

Tommy.

Comment: Did you add the `autodiscover()` lines in the urls.py?

Comment: Yes.  I tried *import permission; permission.autodiscover()* before and after *admin.autodiscover()* just to see what was going on.  Have you used django-permissions by any chance?

Comment: I haven't, but looking at the symptoms I'm 90% positive that this is due a bad integration with the library, because the only calls are failing are those that are "enhanced" by the django-permission library. Have you checked that you followed all the steps correctly  (INSTALLED_APPS, AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS, Apply permission logic, e.t.c)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of this library.

I'm really sorry but the example code was mis-leading. If you follow the Note section which said "From django-permission version 0.8.0, you can specify related object with field__name attribute like django queryset lookup. See the working example below:", the `Article` does not have `author` that's why django blame your code. It should be something like

```
prj1 = Project.objects.create(
    title="Project 1",
    body="hello",
    author=user1,
)
art1 = Article.objects.create(
    title="Article 1",
    body="foobar hogehoge",
    project=prj1,
)
```

Then the example should work.
I'll update the document as soon as possible.

Comment: Many thanks for the feed back.  I'm sory to say that I have moved away from the using this library.